# Remove auto single quotes in GNU Parallel

Tags: gnu-parallel, quoting, single-quotes

I'm running this command, to change "Text to replace" in text files with the basename the text file:

```bash
parallel --dry-run sed -i \"s/Text to replace/{.}/\" {} ::: *.txt
```

However, when there is a space in the text file's filename, Parallel inserts a single quote:

```bash
sed -i "s/Text to replace/'with space'/" 'with space.txt'
```

And without spaces, Parallel doesn't insert a single quote:

```bash
sed -i "s/Text to replace/without_space/" filename_without.txt
```

Is there a way to make Parallel never automatically insert single quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU Parallel shell quotes replacement strings. This is normally what you want:

```
touch "important_file.txt" "not important_file.txt"
parallel rm ::: not*
# Removes 'not important_file.txt' and not: not important_file.txt
```

However, in a few cases you really want full control of the replacement string. In this case you can tell GNU Parallel to unquote the string:

```
parallel --dryrun echo {=uq=} ::: *
```

`uq()` is a perl function, so you can do other stuff in the {==}:

```
parallel --dryrun echo '{= s/a/b/; uq(); =}' ::: *
```

Comment: What's the syntax for applying `uq()` or `Q()` to a column? `Q({1})` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Geremia You cannot use replacement strings in replacement strings. Thus you cannot use `{1}` inside `{=1 =}`. You *can* use `$_`: `{=1 $_ = Q($_) =}` or `{=3 uq=}`